# Django, saving a model: sequence index must be integer, not 'str'

Tags: django, model, indexing, save, sequence

I get this error when i try to save a model whole variables are from POST request.
I don't understand error, what is sequence index?
The code of saving function is:

```
try:
    product=Product()
    product.name=request.POST.get('name',None)
    product.save()
    return HttpResponse('Saved')
except:
    return HTTPServerError("Error during save operation")
```

where name is a CharField

EDIT:

The model is:

```
class Product(models.Model):

      id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

       name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

The stacktrace is printed in javascript console because it is ajax request. So i get the error with `console.log(response.responseText);` and there is only error message and environment variables (i think that there is a way to print all stacktrace, but i don't know it by now).

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the ``Product`` model?

Comment: it would be pretty sweet to see the entire stack trace as well

Comment: For starters, shouldn't you check for form.is_valid() and assign by using product.name = form.cleaned_data['name'] / form.cleaned_data.get('name') ?

Comment: Not always, but I'd prefer to be adding values to a model that I know are valid :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
try:
    product=Product(request.POST)
    product.save()
    return HttpResponse('Saved')
except:
    return HTTPServerError("Error during save operation")
```